# compass fails on arch

Tags: ruby, gruntjs, archlinux, compass

Running `grunt serve` which use to work I'm having this error message.

`` Running "compass:server" (compass) task
    Warning: Command failed: compass --version
 /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:179:in `rescue in specs': Your bundle is locked to chunky_png (1.3.4), but that version could not be found in any of the sources listed in your Gemfile. If you haven't changed sources, that means the author of chunky_png (1.3.4) has removed it. You'll need to update your bundle to a different version of chunky_png (1.3.4) that hasn't been removed in order to install. (Bundler::GemNotFound)
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:173:in `specs'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:233:in `specs_for'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/definition.rb:222:in `requested_specs'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:118:in `block in definition_method'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:19:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `setup'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:133:in `rescue in require'
        from /usr/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
        from /usr/bin/compass:6:in `<main>' ``

So on side I ran a `compass --version` and I obtain the same error `Your bundle is locked to chunky_png (1.3.4),` etc.

Trying to `bundle install` seems a bit useless...

`$ bundle install
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory`

So I tried to reinstall [ruby-compass](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ruby-compass/) because `which compass` sent me to `/usr/bin/compass` which is the one set by **ruby-compass** AUR package.

that did'nt solved the problem. Any idea around ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by installing [compass](http://compass-style.org/) via [pacgem](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pacgem/)

details of commands :

1. to install [pacgem](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/pacgem/)

`cd ~/devel/aur.archlinux.org/     # or where ever you used to put your AUR 
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/pacgem.git
cd pacgem
cat PKGBUILD # at this point, it is recommended to personally check to PKGBUILD
makepkg -si`

and answer `y` to all questions

2. install [compass](http://compass-style.org/)

`pacgem compass`

and answer `y` to all questions. It will install needed dependencies.